# Resize Image for more than one Image Size profile automatically

Tags: rules, media

Here is my problem.

I have field BigPicture in a my Product Content Type.

Is there a way that When I upload an image from BigPicture Field that the current picture automatically resize in more than one image profile.

Here is the desire Image Resize Workflow:

1- Upload the image

2- Automatically Resize and Crop the image in more than one size property (Thumb :120px X 120px, Big : 250px X 250px, ExtraBig 1024px X 760px)

3- The Final File Name for each image should be like MyImageName_Thumb.jpg, MyImageName_Big.jpg, MyImageName_ExtraBig.jpg

I'am using Drupal 7

Thanks a lot

Comment: Drupal prepares image according to styles on display, not on upload. Why don't you like that? And why do you want to change names? Division into subdirectories is not enough?

Answer (score 1):

Image styles in [Imagecache Actions](https://www.drupal.org/project/imagecache_actions) should handle this for you. But as said above, it will do it on display, not on upload. It will scale/crop however you like (there are extra sub modules for this), and the styles will be sorted into folders by image style, but not rename them. But it will put them in folders like Thumb/MyImageName, Big/MyImageName, etc.

Imagecache actions does have a custom option, I'm not sure if it would let you rename the file:

> Custom Actions - Execute your own PHP/GD code in the middle of an
>   imagecache generation process. Requires some familiarity with imageAPI
>   internals.